# Chaining endless sql and performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am chaining `sql` according to user filter which is unknown.

For instance he would like to first ask for certain dates :

```
def filterDates(**kwargs):
    q = ('''
        SELECT date_num, {subject_col}, {in_col} as {out_col}
        FROM {base} 
        WHERE date_num BETWEEN {date1} AND {date2}
        ORDER BY date_num
        ''').format(subject_col=subject_col,**kwargs)
    return q
```

(`base` is input query string from previous, see next)

and then he wants to calculate another thing(or many) so we pass the dates filter string query `q` as `base` to this query:

```
WITH BS AS (
            SELECT date_num, {subject_col}, {in_col}
            FROM {base}
        )
        SELECT t1.{subject_col},t1.{in_col}, t2.{in_col} - t1.{in_col} as {out_col}
        FROM BS t1 
        JOIN BS t2 
        ON t1.{subject_col} = t2.{subject_col} AND t2.date_num = {date2} 
        WHERE t1.date_num = {date1}
 
        ''').format(subject_col=subject_col,**kwargs)
```

Here the `{base}` is going to be :

```
base='('+q+')'+'AS base'
```

Now we can chain queries as much as we want and it works.

1. How would the engine handle this ? is that means that the efficiency is bad because engine has to make 2 rounds ( instead of having a normal `WHERE` on the dates? ) how would he optimize this?
2. Is there a *common* good practice way to chain unknown number of queries?

Comment: 1. Yes and no, depends on the circumstances; Yes and no because it depends on the circumstances; Mainly by pushing the filters down, or other means, again, that depends. 2. In terms of performance: No. In terms of flexibility and a query system that is easier to understand especially by non SQL speakers: yes, why not.

Comment: thanks, does it have a popular term? something I can read more about? I just can't find other people's work in this field because it has no term that helps Google

Comment: None that I knew of. Maybe "nesting queries" or something similar will find something?